# Heart Animation on click

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, css-animations

So Id like to create an animation where you click on the heart that there is a circle around that heart that's scales up and then fades away. I've tried to give the SVG a border but nothing shows up? I'm honestly not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I want it to be similar to the Twitter heart but without the dots around the heart when you click it. Here is a link to my codepen https://codepen.io/Brushel/pen/MEEYgQ

```js
(function() {
  var animatedHeart, heartanimation, heartanimationthree;

  animatedHeart = document.getElementById('heart1');

  heartanimation = document.getElementById('heart2');

  heartanimationthree = document.getElementById('heart3');

  animatedHeart.addEventListener('click', function() {
    return animatedHeart.classList.toggle('fill');
  });

  heartanimation.addEventListener('click', function() {
    return heartanimation.classList.toggle('fillup');
  });

  heartanimationthree.addEventListener('click', function() {
    return heartanimationthree.classList.toggle('heartscale');
  });

}).call(this);
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  height: 100vh;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.col-12 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
          flex: 0 0 100%;
}

#heart1 {
  max-height: 70px;
  fill: white;
  stroke: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fill {
  -webkit-animation: love .5s linear alternate forwards;
          animation: love .5s linear alternate forwards;
  stroke: #D22128;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes love {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    stroke: #D22128;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke: #D22128;
    fill: #D22128;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(5px);
            transform: translateY(5px);
  }
  100% {
    stroke: transparent;
    fill: #D22128;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes love {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    stroke: #D22128;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke: #D22128;
    fill: #D22128;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(5px);
            transform: translateY(5px);
  }
  100% {
    stroke: transparent;
    fill: #D22128;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
#heart2 {
  max-height: 70px;
  fill: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fillup {
  -webkit-animation: lovebutton .5s alternate forwards;
          animation: lovebutton .5s alternate forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes lovebutton {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    fill: #D22128;
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
    fill: #D22128;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    fill: #D22128;
  }
}

@keyframes lovebutton {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    fill: #D22128;
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
    fill: #D22128;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
    fill: #D22128;
  }
}
#heart3 {
  max-height: 70px;
  fill: white;
  stroke: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.heartscale {
  -webkit-animation: heart-beat .5s alternate forwards;
          animation: heart-beat .5s alternate forwards;
  stroke-width: 0px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes heart-beat {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
            transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
            transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
    fill: #D22128;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
            transform: scale(1, 1);
    fill: #D22128;
  }
}

@keyframes heart-beat {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
            transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
            transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
    fill: #D22128;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
            transform: scale(1, 1);
    fill: #D22128;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h2>Animated Hearts</h2>
      <div class="circle">
  <svg class="mo-icon__svg" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve" id="heart1">
<g id="icon_x5F_wishlist">
 <g transform="translate(0,-952.36218)">
  <path class="st0" id="st0" d="M15.33293,980.7616c-19.11968,19.8092-19.10147,51.68518,0,71.51379l84.61456,87.86926
   c28.23759-29.25574,56.47517-58.51135,84.71275-87.76758c19.11969-19.80969,19.11969-51.70477,0-71.51422
   c-19.12007-19.80945-49.90512-19.80994-69.02521,0l-15.58933,16.15155l-15.68754-16.25305
   c-19.12008-19.80945-49.90513-19.80945-69.02521,0L15.33293,980.7616z"/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
    </div>
<!--     End of the first Heart     -->
        
        <svg class="mo-icon__svg" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve" id="heart2">
<g id="icon_x5F_wishlist">
 <g transform="translate(0,-952.36218)">
  <path class="st0" id="st0" d="M15.33293,980.7616c-19.11968,19.8092-19.10147,51.68518,0,71.51379l84.61456,87.86926
   c28.23759-29.25574,56.47517-58.51135,84.71275-87.76758c19.11969-19.80969,19.11969-51.70477,0-71.51422
   c-19.12007-19.80945-49.90512-19.80994-69.02521,0l-15.58933,16.15155l-15.68754-16.25305
   c-19.12008-19.80945-49.90513-19.80945-69.02521,0L15.33293,980.7616z"/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
      
<!--    End of second heart    -->
      
      <svg class="mo-icon__svg" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve" id="heart3">
<g id="icon_x5F_wishlist">
 <g transform="translate(0,-952.36218)">
  <path class="st0" id="st0" d="M15.33293,980.7616c-19.11968,19.8092-19.10147,51.68518,0,71.51379l84.61456,87.86926
   c28.23759-29.25574,56.47517-58.51135,84.71275-87.76758c19.11969-19.80969,19.11969-51.70477,0-71.51422
   c-19.12007-19.80945-49.90512-19.80994-69.02521,0l-15.58933,16.15155l-15.68754-16.25305
   c-19.12008-19.80945-49.90513-19.80945-69.02521,0L15.33293,980.7616z"/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
      


    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: so you are trying to put a border around a heart?

Comment: Yeah but I don't want the border to touch the heart. I know I could use stoke: {} but I'd like to make the border not touch the heart at all. If that makes any sense @tomsmithweb

Answer (score 0):

the last one looks pretty close ! I think there is a simpler (sort of simpler) way to do this in css.

Nicolas Escoffer has a great article about it here:

Article:
https://blog.prototypr.io/twitter-s-heart-animation-in-full-css-b1c00ca5b774

Code Pen:
https://codepen.io/OxyDesign/pen/avXVbo

otherwise I would suggest creating a keyframes animation that uses the border of the circle div you have created. Be sure to set the circle div outside of the heart .svg so it is not wrapping the element:

I made an example for you below based on your original codepen:

#HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
      <br>
      <div id="circle" class="circle"></div>
       <svg class="mo-icon__svg" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve" id="heart4">
<g id="icon_x5F_wishlist">
    <g transform="translate(0,-952.36218)">
        <path class="st0" id="st0" d="M15.33293,980.7616c-19.11968,19.8092-19.10147,51.68518,0,71.51379l84.61456,87.86926
            c28.23759-29.25574,56.47517-58.51135,84.71275-87.76758c19.11969-19.80969,19.11969-51.70477,0-71.51422
            c-19.12007-19.80945-49.90512-19.80994-69.02521,0l-15.58933,16.15155l-15.68754-16.25305
            c-19.12008-19.80945-49.90513-19.80945-69.02521,0L15.33293,980.7616z"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
  </div>
</body>
```

#SCSS:

```
body {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}

h2{
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  font-size: 3em;
  user-select: none;
  
}

// Set up basic Grid
.container {
  display: block;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding-left: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.col-12{
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

// Fourth Animation


#heart4 {
  max-height: 70px;
  fill: white;
  stroke: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  width: 5rem;
}

.dot-animation {
  position: relative;
}


.dot {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  &:nth-child(1){
    background: #D22128;
    left: 49.7%;
    top: 75px;
  }
   &:nth-child(2){
    background: #D22128;
    left: 49.4%;
    bottom: 8%;
  }
   &:nth-child(3){
    background: #D22128;
    left: 53.5%;
    top: 30px;
  }
   &:nth-child(4){
    background: #D22128;
    left: 45%;
    top: 30px;
  }
}

.bands {
  animation: snap 1s forwards;
  stroke-width: 0;
}

@keyframes snap {
  from { 
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1); 
  filter: brightness(0.5);
  }
  30% {  
    transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1); }
  40% {  
    transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1); }
  50% {  
    transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1); }
  65% {  
    transform: scale3d(.95, 1.05, 1); }
  75% {  
    transform: scale3d(1.05, .95, 1); }
  to {   
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    fill: #D22128; 
    filter: brightness(1);
  }
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: 2.5rem;
  top: 8rem;
}

.burst {
    animation: burst .5s forwards;
}

@keyframes burst {
  0% {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50% 50%;
  width: 0.25rem;
  height: 0.25rem;
    
  }
  100% {
  border: 5px solid white;
  border-radius: 50% 50%;
  width: 7rem;
  height: 7rem;
  margin-left: -.90rem;
  margin-top: -2.45rem;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  }
}
```

#JS:

```
# Grab Element
heartanimationfour = document.getElementById('heart4')
circle = document.getElementById('circle')

# Add event listener for the click
heartanimationfour.addEventListener 'click', ->
  heartanimationfour.classList.toggle 'bands',
  circle.classList.toggle 'burst'
```

https://codepen.io/cwoolf123/pen/wvMdyKq?editors=1111